# My android app isn't displaying anything when i add numbers to it's text field

Tags: java, android, loops, android-layout

I'm new to programming for the android and I'm trying to create a simple program.

If the user enters a number in the attacker ws field and the same number defender ws field you should get an answer.

I'm missing something.

```
package com.example.helloandroid;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class HelloAndroid extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private EditText text, text2, text3;
    private Button btutorial1;

    int result = text.toString().compareTo(text2.toString());





    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("I hope this works");


        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        text2 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);      

        btutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btutorial1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        switch (view.getId()) 
        {
            case R.id.button1:

                if (text.getText().toString().equals(1) && text2.getText().toString().equals(2)) 
                {
                    text3.setText("Five and above");        
                    return;
                }

                else if (text.getText().toString().equals(1) && text2.getText().toString().equals(3)) 
                {
                    text3.setText("Five and above");        
                    return;
                }

                else if (text.getText().toString().equals(1) && text2.getText().toString().equals(3)) 
                {
                    text3.setText("Four and above");        
                    return;
                }

                else if (text.getText().toString().equals(text2.getText().toString())) 
                {
                    text3.setText("Four and above");        
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    text3.setText("Not Working");        
                return;
                }

        }
    }


}
```

My XML class named main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Enter Attacker ws"></TextView>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:text="" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:inputType="number" android:visibility="visible"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Enter Opponent ws"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText2" android:text="" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:visibility="visible" android:inputType="number"></EditText>
     <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Calculate" android:visibility="visible" android:onClick="myClickHandler"></Button>
     <EditText android:id="@+id/editText3"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"  android:name="result" android:editable="false"></EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comparing two integers then do this.

```
int number1 = Integer.parseInt(text);
int number2= Integer.parseInt(text2);
```

now in if condition compare number1 and number2.

```
if (number1 == number2)
 { 
 text3.setText("Four and above");
 return;
 }
```

Remember this will work only for integers. for any string you will get exception you can handle it later on.

Comment: That's not going to work. It won't accept parse for arguments type edittext

Comment: i am sorry.. but it will work for 'int number1 = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());' same goes for 'int number2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString());'

Comment: You can compare if they are greater than or less than in this case very easily by simply saying `if(number1>number2)` or `if(number1<number2)`.. :)

Comment: that does not work and I've tried (text.getText().toString() > (text2.getText().toString()))

Comment: thats what i am telling you. You can not compare two strings in this way. You need to parse them first to integers. here is full code now 
'int number1 = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
int number2 = Integer.parseInt(text2.getText().toString();
'

now in if case use

`if(number1>number2)'

Answer (score 2):

In java with objects == checks if 2 variables have the same memory location, not that they are the same value. Use .equals() instead and it should work

Comment: Sorry, I missed something else. The code should be in onClick not myClickHandler.

Answer (score 0):

if you are planning to compare text then use use `text.getText().toString().equals(text2.getText().toString())`

Comment: That's not working either. I narrow the error to Java not holding the value the user enter.

Comment: btw you should call `myClickHandler(src) ` from your `onClick(View src)` method

Comment: Do you know how to write text greater then text 2 in textedit

Comment: do you want to compare two numbers ? If so then you need to parse the texts using Integer.parseInt() or something similar as suggested by Harshad in the answer below

Comment: I want to compare two strings use text edit argument and see which one is greater then the other.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `compare two strings and see which one is greater then the other`. Fro strings you can compare lengths. Nothing else comes to my mind. Can you explain what do you exactly want to compare ?

Comment: My program works like this, compare to two numbers to which one is greater then the other. I use edit-text statement to hold the value the user enter. Then I use if statements to see if one number is greater then the other. for example ext.getText().toString().equals(text2.getText().toString()) works. so how do you text > text2. tried if (text >= text2) . However eclipse says I can't use operators in edit-text statement.

Comment: Ok. There is now way to identify whether the strings you are comparing are numbers or not. For that what you need to do is parse them using something like what Harshad mentioned, get the numbers and then compare them.